# Android - sharedPreference are not working as it should?

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences

I have an ArrayList of string in my activity and  i want to store it as onPause in SharedPreference and retrieve it in my onCreate() but i am unable to do that.

here is my code -:

```
public static ArrayList<String> ignoredTasks;
public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "savedPreferences";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    ignoredTasks =  loadBackStates();
}
@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onPause();
    Log.e(TAG, "I am pause");
    saveState();
}
@Override
public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    Log.e(TAG, "I am stop");
    saveState();
}
@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    super.onDestroy();
    Log.e(TAG, "i am destroy");
    saveState();
}

public void saveState()
{
    SharedPreferences spr = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = spr.edit();
    int size = ignoredTasks.size();
    editor.putInt("size", size);
    for(int k = 0; k < size-1; k++)
    {
        editor.putString(k+"4", ignoredTasks.get(k));
        editor.commit();
    }

    //editor.commit();
}
public ArrayList<String> loadBackStates()
{
     ArrayList<String> ignoredTask = new ArrayList<String>();
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    int size = sp.getInt("size", 0);
    for(int k = 0; k < size-1; k++)
    {
        ignoredTask.add(k, sp.getString(k + "4", " "));
    }
    return ignoredTask;

}


public void createMenuDialog(final int i, Drawable icon, final String taskName, final String pkgName)
{
    final AlertDialog.Builder menuDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    menuDialog.setIcon(icon);
     menuDialog.setTitle(taskName);
menuDialog.setItems(menuItems, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                    /* User clicked so do some stuff */
                    String[] items = menuItems;

                    if(items[which].equals("Ignore"))
                    {
                        HashMap<String,String> newItem = new HashMap<String,String>();
                        newItem.put("Process", pkgName);
                        newItem.put("Name", taskName);
                        ignored.add(newItem);
                        ignoredTasks.add(pkgName);
                    }                                               
                }
            });
     menuDialog.show();
}
```

The problem is when i exit my app using back key and then if i restart it again, i could see the sharedpreference but when i force close my app then its gone. what's the issue?

Please Help!!

Thanks

Comment: hi i think when you force close onPause method will not be called... Ensure whether it is called...

Comment: yeah you are right onPause() did not get a call on force close....any solution for this problem?

Comment: can you try it in onDestroy method...

Comment: Tried but even onDestroy did not get a call...seriously whats wrong with my app..!!

Comment: tried and i also put Log.d in it but the strange thing is even this function did not get a call on force close....STRANGE!!

Comment: k tell me how you are force closing the application...

Comment: settings - application - manage applications - selecting my app and force closing it

Comment: how u r going to setting activity....

Comment: by pressing menu button.

Comment: by presseing menu button from your activity right... its fine... its better for you call onpause method before starting the settings intent... Hope it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this one..

```
SharedPreferences spr =  activity.getSharedPreferences("SPR", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

try this - maybe it will help..

```
for(int k = 0; k < size-1; k++)
{
    editor.putString(k+"4", ignoredTasks.get(k));

}
editor.commit();
```

Comment: @CapDroid problem still exists :(

Comment: @Capdroid actually the problem is that whenever i force close my app, onPause is not getting a call that is why its unable to save state of my app. any idea why it isn't getting a call and how to solve this issue?

Comment: it is there in my real code ...i just forgot to write it here :( the thing is even onDestroy() was not called on force close!!!! what a weird situation.

Comment: onPause() is also didn't called?

Comment: nope :( `05-02 17:29:17.672: INFO/ActivityManager(59): Force stopping package com.varundroid.util.IgnoreList uid=10036
05-02 17:29:17.672: INFO/Process(59): Sending signal. PID: 1118 SIG: 9` this is what i am getting in logcat and no log.e message has been printed.

Comment: nope when i use back buttong every function did get a call as they should but when i force close it like this settings - application - manage applications - selecting my app and force closing it ...none of them has been called and got only these two lines(which i have pasted above) in logcat. :(

Comment: sorry man for asking you stupid questions :P actually there was small mistake in my code. now its working fine. Thanks for your efforts. i really appreciate it.

Comment: The ArrayList which i was saving and the one i was using were two different Arraylists. I know its a stupid mistake ...i am so sorry but i really appreciate your efforts. Thanks mate...cheers!!

Answer (score 1):

Try with [getSharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getSharedPreferences%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) instead of getPreferences

Edit: I have read the logcat lines you have posted in a comment. Android is sending to your app a SIGKILL signal when you force close so I think you can't do anything. Read this. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGKILL

Comment: @Rafaesp still not working. After force close evrything is in SharedPreference was gone. :(

Comment: Maybe when you force close, the activity doesn't pause. Use Logcat to see if it's saving.

Comment: Try calling saveState in onDestroy()

Comment: tried and i also put Log.d in it but the strange thing is even this function did not get a call on force close....STRANGE!!

Comment: to appreciate ur efforts i voted up your answer. Thanks for trying to help me. Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

Force close terminates your app instantly, without any other code being called.  This is not weird, this is how things work.

It sounds like you've logged that onPause() gets called when you press Back.  You should also check that onPause() is called when moving into another activity or app.  For instance, long-press the Home button and select another app, you should see your onPause() log.

That should be enough for your purposes.  Why do you think you need onPause() to get called after a force close (which is impossible)?